# Is it possible to find np.count_nonzero of each row of matrix without for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I want to find the row which has non-zero values more than n times from matrix and clean it but I can come up only with `for` loop way.

For example, clean the row of matrix `aaa` which has value more than 5 times.

```
aaa = np.zeros([5,8])

aaa[0] = [0,0,0,15,21,10,0,0] <<
aaa[1] = [0,3,7,5,4,0,0,0]
aaa[2] = np.random.randint(3, size=8)
aaa[3] = np.random.randint(15, size=8)
print aaa
>> [[  0.   0.   0.  15.  21.  10.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   3.   7.   5.   4.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  1.   1.   2.   0.   2.   1.   1.   1.]
 [ 10.   9.  12.   2.  11.  12.  12.  12.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]

for row in range(5):
    print np.count_nonzero(aaa[row])
    if np.count_nonzero(aaa[row]) > 5:
        aaa[row] = 0
print aaa
>>>[[  0.   0.   0.  15.  21.  10.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   3.   7.   5.   4.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.] # clean
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.] # clean
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

In fact, what I want to do is cleaning stationary noise in each row and keeping Gaussian-like peak value row. My real data matrix is very large (dimension = 10^5 x 10^6). Is there any super fast way to clean the row in this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.count_nonzero` on the entire array -

```
arr[np.count_nonzero(arr,axis=1) > 5] = 0
```

A faster version would be to get the boolean array of non-zeros and then do the counting -

```
arr[np.count_nonzero(arr!=0,axis=1) > 5] = 0
```

Alternatively, use `ndarray.sum` -

```
arr[(arr!=0).sum(axis=1) > 5] = 0
```